# maven dependency conflicts with grizzly-websockets and grizzly-http-servlet

Tags: java, sockets, grizzly

Maven:

```
    <!-- Grizzly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-websockets</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-comet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Despite them all being the same version, I'm running into an exception within these libraries.  When I alter the version numbers I just get various other errors related to classes not having methods and stuff.  My logs show that the URL is being mapped correctly to the socket.  This exception occurs when a browser opens the socket connection.

I'm trying to use `[portal-java][1]` with the Atmosphere module.

```
WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.initialize(Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/Request;Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/HttpResponsePacket;Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/filterchain/FilterChainContext;Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/utils/DelayedExecutor$DelayQueue;Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServerFilter;)Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/SuspendStatus;
    at org.atmosphere.container.Grizzly2WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication$G2WebSocket.<init>(Grizzly2WebSocketSupport.java:225)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Grizzly2WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication.createSocket(Grizzly2WebSocketSupport.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(WebSocketEngine.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(WebSocketEngine.java:187)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.doServerUpgrade(WebSocketFilter.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleServerHandshake(WebSocketFilter.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleHandshake(WebSocketFilter.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleRead(WebSocketFilter.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:378)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to get their snapshot....

```
<repositories>
    <!-- Added to get the Atmosphere 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, can be removed when 1.1.0 is released -->
    <repository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes have been submitted to the Atmosphere folks to support Grizzly 2.3.  These changes haven't been released.

I would recommend following up on their mailing lists to determine which snapshot release has the changes and when the next release is.